# An example of functions on a groupoid

Tags: c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, groupoids

There are two $C^\ast$-algebras associated to the $\ast$-algebra (under a convolution and the usual involution) $$C_c(G) := \{ f:G\longrightarrow \mathbb C :\:f \text{ has compact support}\}$$ of compactly supported continuous functions on a locally compact groupoid $G$: its completions in the norms 
$$ 
\|f\|_{\max} := \sup \{\|\pi(f)\|:\:\pi \text{ is a bounded involutive representation of C_c(G)}\},
$$
$$
\|f\|_r := \sup \{\|\pi_x(f)\|:\: x\in G^0 \},
$$
where $\pi_x$ is a regular representation in the fiber of $x$ under the target map.

Many references on groupoid $C^\ast$-algebras give the following example. Let $G$ be the groupoid of the equivalence relation on the set
$$X:= [0,1]\times\{0,1\}$$
given by $(x,0)\sim (x,1)$ for $x \in (0,1).$ Marcolli writes in her ``Lectures on Arithmetic Noncommutative Geometry'' that the corresponding quotient space has no interesting functions, while the convolution algebra on $G$ is $$C_c(G) = \{f:G\longrightarrow C([0,1])\otimes M_{2}(\mathbb C):\: f(0),\,f(1) \text{ are diagonal} \}.$$ None of the sources I've found explain this description of $C_c(G)$ in detail sufficient for my understanding. So I ask
$$\fbox{Question: Why does $C_c(G)$ have the above form for this groupoid?}$$

Comment: Did you mean $(x,0)\sim (x,1)$ iff $x\not\in\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Hint: Do you understand the case where $X=\{a,b\}$ and $a\sim b$? And the case where $X=\{a,b\}$ with the trivial equivalence relation?

Comment: @Rasmus yes, I do mean that. Corrected in the question. Thanks. I will think about those cases.